# CSS current / active li

Tags: javascript, css

Just doing a ajax page, which utilises ul li menu.

DEMO : http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/ajax/

The code is ( css )

```
#top #menu{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
} 

#top #menu li{
    position:relative;
    left:300px;
    top:-22px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3399ff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline;
}

#top #menu li:hover{
    color: #ec008c;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

The html is:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="home">Info</li>
    <li id="press">Press</li>
    <li id="trade">Trade</li>
</ul>
```

The links fire ajax request via jquery, to dynamically load internal and external pages... thats not the issue.

I cannot put li current or li active.

The menu needs to remain as is, so I am thinking surely there must be a css method, for showing the menu like so: ( when we are on that ajax page. )

INFO   **PRESS**  TRADE

So say we click the PRESS link, we can control its effect on page. In other words, it is underlines or bold.. or whatever. Sort of a class="selected" or "active" ... I am stumped

Comment: Why can't you add a class to the `<li>` as needed?

Comment: Yeah, just add an `active` class to the active `li` element and style that by adding an `li.active` rule. Why are you stumped?

Comment: yep tried that , doesnt wanna comply... I have: #top #menu li.active{
 text-decoration:underline;}

Comment: Just call it something else then. What's the other `active` class for anyway?

Comment: I will fire a demo up bear with me

Comment: Demo: http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/ajax/

Comment: Can you add the `active` class so we can see how it doesn't comply? And where is `#top #menu li.active {text-decoration:underline;}`? It's not there in your `main.css`.

Comment: I have added code as per @jason gennaro suggestion. Still no go.

Comment: You need to change the active element to `<li id="press" class="active">Press</li>` and add a CSS rule `#top #menu li.active {text-decoration:underline;}`.

Comment: Surely tho changing id="press" class="active" blah blah ... wont dynamically change across the page, because the content is being fetched via ajax, the menu remains constant and isnt constructed dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your menu.js file, try adding this to your code:

```
//Manage click events
sections.click(function(){
    //show the loading bar
    showLoading();

    // ADD THIS?
    sections.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //load selected section
    switch(this.id){
        case "home": // etc etc...
```

Now just add some lovely CSS for this...

```
#menu li.current {
    font-weight:bold; /* or whatever... */
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: sorry, i originally typed `sections` as `$sections` -- i just edited/fixed this.

Comment: Managed to do it, by changing #menu li.current to #top #menu li.current

Comment: Ok this works perfect, however the current page ( li ) isnt highlighted, I suppose because we havent added class="active" or class="current" ( latter being the case in your example. Works A1 thankyou... will try the current class, on the li

Comment: class="current" yep, that fixed it... wooohoo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is the way you are adding the `:active`

You wrote

"I have: `#top #menu li.active{text-decoration:underline;}`"

You need

`#top #menu li:active{font-weight:bold;}`

Notice the `:` instead of the `.`

Also notice you need to make the style `font-weight` instead of `text-decoration` as you are already doing `text-decoration` on the `:hover`.

Comment: Yeah I tried all conceivable versions prior to posting on Stack, which is why I was annoyed someone voted my question down. Amazing. Anyhoo, have updated the css , but still no go :(

Comment: @422.  I voted you back up!  Have you tried to make the styling more specific?  So `ul#menu li:active{}`, using the element tag in the rule?

Comment: Yeah have done those changes, I hadnt noticed I had cross contaminated the style.. thanks for the pointer, still no joy tho.. I am thinking we need to use a sombination of css and js to achieve this, and appoint a selector to the element

Comment: Why `:`? This will only apply the styles while it is being clicked.

Comment: @melhosseiny Yes.  But in the code example in the previous set of comments, @422 wrote `.active` instead of `:active` when he specifically said he wanted an selector for when the element is clicked... at least that is how I read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of jquery to add an active class to the clicked menu item.

Check out the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/K6F8m/

Comment: I cannot get that working with this code, Info remains active.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to the link when a user clicks on it, and remove it from all other links.

```
$('#menu a').live('click', function(){
   $('#menu a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then style the css class.

Answer (score 1):

In your click function add a line that add an `active` class to the item that was clicked, and remove the `active` class from the other items.

Answer (score 1):

You need both JS and CSS for this.

**JS**

```
sections.click(function(){
    ...
    sections.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    ...
});
```

**CSS**

```
#top #menu li.active { text-decoration:underline; }
```